# Is it possible to assign different values to a list of symbol, where they have the same argument?

Tags: list-manipulation

I created a list of symbols which has "x" as argument. My question is wheather is it possible to assign different value to each member of the list.

```
Lt = 250*10^-6; 
n = 10;
L = Lt/n; 
Lbal = Table[i, {i, 0, Lt, L}]
Tbal = Table[Symbol["T" <> ToString@i][x], {i, n + 1}];
```

Now the thing i want is to replace the argument of the Tbal vector's "i"th element with the "i"th element of the L vector

Thanks for the replies in advance.
Yours sincerly:
David

Comment: Please post self contained code in your questions. I.e., define what `n` and  `Lt` are

Comment: n and Lt are just variables, but here is the code you've requested:
Lt = 250*10^-6;
n = 10;
L = Lt/n;
Lbal = Table[i, {i, 0, Lt, L}]
Tbal = Table[Symbol["T" <> ToString@i][x], {i, n + 1}];

Comment: Why do you need to do things this way? Why don't you name your variables `T[1]`, `T[2]`, etc. using `Array[T, n+1, 0]`? Then you can do `MapThread[#1@#2 &, {Array[T, n + 1, 0], Lbal}]` or just `Table[T[kk][Lbal[kk+1], {kk, 0, n}]` or some such.

Comment: The only reason i wanted to do this way, that i'm not so familiar with the program yet, but thank you for showing other ways to get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
Lt = 10; n = 2;
L = Lt/n;
Lbal = Table[i, {i, 0, Lt, L}];
Tbal = Table[Symbol["T" <> ToString@i][x], {i, Lbal}]
{T0[x], T5[x], T10[x]}
```

Or like this:

```
Lt = 250*10^-6;
n = 10;
L = Lt/n;
Lbal = Table[i, {i, 0, Lt, L}];
Tbal = Table[Symbol["T" <> ToString@i], {i, n + 1}];
MapThread[Function[{head, body}, head[body]], {Tbal, Lbal}]
{T1[0], T2[1/40000], T3[1/20000], T4[3/40000], T5[1/10000], 
 T6[1/8000], T7[3/20000], T8[7/40000], 
  T9[1/5000], T10[9/40000], T11[1/4000]}
```

Comment: actually i want this to look like this
Lbal={1,2,3,4}
Tbal={T1[x],T2[x],T3[x],T4[x]}

Tbalnew={T1[1],T2[2],T3[3],T[4]}

Comment: Thank you so much that was the solution i've looked for

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways.

```
MapThread[#1 /. x -> #2 &, {Tbal, Lbal}]
MapThread[#1 /. #2 &, {Tbal, Thread[x -> Lbal]}]
MapIndexed[#1 /. x -> Extract[Lbal, #2] &, Tbal]
Module[{i = 1}, Tbal /. x :> Lbal[[i++]]]
Tbal /. List /@ Thread[x -> Lbal] // Diagonal
```